# Foundation wall slanting towards deck

Tags: drywall, foundation

I bought my first home in Sep 2020 and redid the old deck since all of the planks in the old deck were rotting away.

When we reinstalled the deck, we had the deck raised in height and also increased in length by 2 inches.

Recently, I noticed that the foundation edge near the deck was slanting towards the deck and small hairline cracks near the area. No other vertical/horizontal cracks, but I wanted to check if this is something that warrants a foundation expert and/or modification of the deck.

Pictured attached:

[image: Slanting edge] (deck on the right)
[image](small hairline cracks)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2H2M.jpg (from freeman below)

I didn't notice them when I bought the home in September 2020, and the property is built in 2000.

Comment: Don't seem alarming. If the foundation has settled, larger cracks will appear on the foundation, as well as the stonewall facet.

Comment: I don't see anything in these pics to cause you concern. When there is settling/foundation issues it'll be more obvious than the hairline crack in the pic. In more severe cases they will run vertically and horizontally through the grout in your stone facade, for example. I think you're good but there are some structural engineers here who will probably chime in.

Comment: That just looks like a hairline crack in parging that has been applied to maybe a block concrete wall or possibly a poured concrete wall.

Comment: You indicate that there's a slant and that the first picture shows it. Is this what you're seeing? https://i.imgur.com/KC33mka.jpg

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong in those pictures.

Comment: @FreeMan - that's exactly right

Comment: I am not sure if the slant is something that I need to be worried about/indicate foundation issues.

Comment: True slanting is associated with uneven foundation settlement, from which, vertical cracks from the foundation extend to the wall will occur. You can do a whole house survey to ensure there is no differential settlement (one side/corner settles more than the others),